# 31st day of every month is coming below the next month. For example 31st of may is coming below June

Tags: mysql, date, calendar

```
select  jiraissue.issuetype, component.cname, issuetype.pname,
        jiraissue.issuestatus,issuestatus.pname, jiraissue.created,
        CONCAT(monthname(jiraissue.created)," ",
                    year(jiraissue.created)) as monthyear,
        jiraissue.RESOLUTIONDATE,
        count(jiraissue.id), avg(DateDIFF(jiraissue.RESOLUTIONDATE,
        jiraissue.created)) as days_to_close,
        month(jiraissue.Created) as month
    from  project
    join  jiraissue  ON project.id=jiraissue.project
    join  issuetype  ON jiraissue.issuetype = issuetype.id
    JOIN  issuestatus  ON jiraissue.issuestatus = issuestatus.id
    left JOIN  nodeassociation  ON jiraissue.id = nodeassociation.source_node_id
    left JOIN  component  ON nodeassociation.sink_node_id = component.id
    where  project.pkey='EWSMSP'
      and  jiraissue.RESOLUTIONDATE is not null
      and  jiraissue.created > {{since}}
      and  issuetype.pname in('Incident')
    group by  month
    order by  month
```

[image: Table]

As you can see the first one is created 31st march but in Month column its shows April. Same for the 3rd record as well.

Comment: Are all the records with date = 31 have `monthyear` as the next one? Or only a few records have this issue? If only few records have this issue, could it be because of some time zone problem?

Comment: Yes all records have the same issue. Can't we give some condition like time is between '00:00:00' to '23:59:59'?

Comment: See [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: How are you formatting the "Created" and "Resolutiondate" columns?

Comment: A time zone issue? March 31 at 20:05 in one time zone could easily fall on April 1 in another time zone.

Comment: Yes it is a problem of timezone